Creating a rule in lighttpd to have multiple hosts point to the same folder
With this configuration

$HTTP["host"] == "^(ch\.)?pool.ntp.org$" {
    accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/pool.ntp.org_access.log"
    $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/$" {
        url.redirect = ( "" => "https://ntppool.org" )
        url.redirect-code = 302
    }
}

We attempt to redirect traffic for both ch.pool.ntp.org or pool.ntp.org to the same destination but they seem to go to the default. What are we doing wrong?

There were a couple of errors in the configuration.

the host is a regexp and so == should be replaced with =~
the url is unimportant to us so remove matching

The resulting correctly behaving config:
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(ch\.)?pool.ntp.org" {
    accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/pool.ntp.org_access.log"
    $HTTP["url"] =~ "" {
        url.redirect = ( "" => "https://ntppool.org" )
        url.redirect-code = 302
    }
}

might need more improvements (open to suggestions in the comments) but this seems to work.
